# How to relocate Windows 10 "Movies" and "Music" folder, that have been assigned to an inaccessible drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, nas

I have previously assigned my system "Movies" and "Music" folders in Windows 10 to corresponding folders in my NAS (network storage). Now I have changed my router and the new router has different network configuration. The old one was giving IP's in the 192.168.1.xx range, and the new one works with 192.168.50.xx range (and it doesn't seem to be possible to change, I tried).

So now I am trying to reassign the "Movies" and "Music" folders to a new network address, but Windows tell me it can't be done, because the old network address in not accessible. Trying to restore the defaults gives the same result. What should I do?

The only thing that comes to my mind is to connect the old router back, then restore the defaults, then connect the new router and relocate again. But I am afraid Windows will then try to move all my movies and music to drive C, there's not enough space for that.

Comment: Do you have a second computer that could run SMB file sharing? What model of NAS is it?

Comment: 1. No
2. Iomega idx-2
But actually I've just solved it myself, thank you!

Comment: Please post an answer describing your solution, in that case.

Comment: I've just done it. I've been writing it when I saw you comment and decided to reply to you first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem just required a bit more patience.

In case anyone else has the same question, I'll leave it here.

1. Right-click on the "Movies" folder icon in "My PC" screen, select "Properties" in the bottom.
2. Go to "Location" tab, click "Move". In Explorer window, select "Network" and type the new IP of the NAS. Select the folder you need.
3. Click "OK", then **wait**. Don't click anything else - that will hang and/or crush the Explorer.
4. An error message appears, telling that it couldn't find the old folder. Click "Ignore all", then **wait again**.
5. A new message appears, asking if you want to move all files from the old location to the new one. Click "No".
6. You're done!